# Refreshing image when text changes

Tags: javascript

I am working with a form. There is a button to upload images to the server. Once the image is uploaded, a form field gets the image file name.
I also have an `<img scr>` which shows a default image.
What I need is that when the user uploads an image, this image should be shown instead of the default image.
This is the form field that receives the uploaded image file name:

```
<input type="text" name="imagen" id="imagen" value="" size="32" onInput ="javascript:reloadpic();">
```

And this is the script that should be launched:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        <!--

        function reloadpic()
        {

         alert ("ha cambiado");
         var timestamp = new Date().getTime();
         var image = "http://../platos/"+document.getElementById("imagen").value;
         document.images["imagenplato"].src = image;
         setTimeout("reloadpic();", 1000);
        }



         -->
</script>
```

But it is never launched. 
Any help is welcome.

Comment: This might be helpful: [Preview an image before it is uploaded](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459379/preview-an-image-before-it-is-uploaded)

Comment: remove <!-- --> from your script tag. Right now, your whole function is commented and is undefined.

Comment: @NikolaR., JavaScript don't have these comments.

Comment: @AfzaalAhmadZeeshan it does indeed, as you can see, it is written in HTML, not in separate JS file.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you're having an `input[type="text"]` that is not used for image purposes.

I think you need to change that to `input[type="file"]` and then trigger some events. Maybe you need to change your event to `onchange=""`.

Comment: Thank you, but the input is correct. On that field is shown the name of the file, not the image itself. On another part of the page is an <img src> where the image should be shown.